# Can start, but not join, a chat when <20 rep points

Tags: bug, reputation, chat

I am receiving some excellent feedback on a recent post in Workplace, which has spawned a bit of a dialogue in comments. No surprise, I was urged to start a chat, which I did -- but then I couldn't sign into the chat!

My Workplace user account is rather new (as is this one on Meta) so I don't have the rep to join a chat.

It seems like a bug to allow me to start one, though. I don't know what the other user saw, whether or not he got "spammed" with an unfruitful chat session.

Comment: What do you mean "start chat"? Create a room? Invite other user? If you mean just see a room you should be able to even without any account.

Comment: I mean, I got that message in the comment thread, and I clicked on the link. That took me to a page (presumably a chat room) but also displayed a login box. Attempting to log in gave me that message.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce now because I earned some points. (Maybe we could try it in this comment thread, though...?)

Comment: Not really a bug. It's a well known issue with a pending request to change it.